# should the inFile be placed before -o flag or after?

Tags: c++, g++, gnu

Supposing you have several files, say "file1.C" and "file2.C", then they can be compiled into an executable program named "myprog"

I noticed that in some tutorials the following command is used:

```
g++ file1.C file2.C -o myprog
```

while  others:

```
g++ -o myprog  file1.C file2.C
```

my question is are these two forms are essentially the same? and which is more formal?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments can be in any order. As far as which is more formal -- dealer's choice!